# Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getFilter() from the type JobsListAdapter

Tags: android, filter

i try to Filter custom listview and after write code of filter

and when call it

```
    JobsListAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString().toLowerCase());
```

and the problem said

Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getFilter() from the type JobsListAdapter

```
public Filter getFilter()
        {
            if(filter == null)
                filter = new MangaNameFilter();
            return filter;
        }

     public  class MangaNameFilter extends Filter
        {

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                // NOTE: this function is *always* called from a background thread, and
                // not the UI thread.
                constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
                FilterResults result = new FilterResults();
                if(constraint != null && constraint.toString().length() > 0)
                {
                    ArrayList<Jobs> filt = new ArrayList<Jobs>();
                    ArrayList<Jobs> lItems = new ArrayList<Jobs>();
                    synchronized (this)
                    {
                        lItems.addAll(values);
                    }
                    for(int i = 0, l = lItems.size(); i < l; i++)
                    {
                        Jobs m = lItems.get(i);
                        if(m.name.toLowerCase().contains(constraint))
                            filt.add(m);
                    }
                    result.count = filt.size();
                    result.values = filt;
                }
                else
                {
                    synchronized(this)
                    {
                        result.values = values;
                        result.count = values.size();
                    }
                }
                return result;
            }

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                // NOTE: this function is *always* called from the UI thread.
                filtered = (ArrayList<Jobs>)results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                clear();
                for(int i = 0, l = filtered.size(); i < l; i++)
                    add(filtered.get(i));
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }

        }
```

please help me

Comment: You need to have an instance of `JobsListAdapter` to call `getFilter()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just what it says. Either you need to make the method `static` or create an instance of the class and access the method that way. Something like

```
JobsListAdapter myClass = new JobsListAdapter();  // enter your params for the constructor
myClass.getFilter().filter(s.toString().toLowerCase());
```

or change the method signature to include the `static` modifier which may or may not be what you want.

```
    public static Filter getFilter()
    {
        if(filter == null)
            filter = new MangaNameFilter();
        return filter;
    }
```

**Just a couple links that may be helpful**

[When to make my method static](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671496/java-when-to-use-static-methods)

[Understanding instance and class members](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

Comment: solution is 

defined JobsListAdapter ad;
 
and call it

ad.getFilter().filter(s.toString().toLowerCase());

Answer (score 0):

it should be if you are trying to get just 1 instance of the filter.

```
public static Filter getFilter()
```

or

```
new JobsListAdapter().getFilter().filter(s.toString().toLowerCase());
```

Depending on what you need.

Comment: What makes you so sure that the method should be static?

Comment: I was writing the other option, but looking at his class i think i would use it static.

Comment: `inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

         

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
              
              JobsListAdapter().getFilter().filter(s.toString().toLowerCase());
            }

        });`

i use it  but the error in 

The method JobsListAdapter() is undefined for the type new TextWatcher(){}

Comment: its new JobsListAdapter() or make the method static.